# How can I change iOS “me” setting permanently?

Tags: ios, settings

The “me” setting in Contacts is associated with my wife’s contact entry rather than mine. I follow the steps to change “me” to my contact entry and it seems to work until the next day when it changes back to my wife. I have iPhone XS Max running iOS 12.1.2

Comment: Do you share an iCloud account?

Comment: No, we have separate iCloud accounts, thanks Tetsujin

Comment: Are you linking contacts through Google, Yahoo, or other service accounts?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around:

1. Signed out of iCloud on my iPhone
2. Signed into iCloud.com with Safari on a Mac.
3. Deleted my and my wife’s contact information
4. re-entered our two contacts via keyboard.
5. signed back into iCloud on my iPhone and let it merge.

So far it looks like the designation of my contact entry as “me” is solid. Time will tell but at this point it has not reverted to my wife’s contact entry.

Comment: Thanks, dwightk, your edit shows me how to make my answer clearer